# Caching data in SharePoint Added EvenReceiver

Tags: caching, sharepoint, event-receiver

I have an event receiver that lsitenes on an "added" event. Inside that receiver I have to retrieve all contents of another list:

```
var refList=Web.Lists.TryGetList("ReferenceData");
var allItems=refList.GetItems();
foreach( var item in allItems) {
// stuff here
}
```

If I do this on the `ItemAdded`-Event each time I have to retrieve all data from the reference list. Because the data in the reference list does not change very often I would prefer to Cache the content and only refresh it once every day. Usually I would try `HttpContext.Cache`, but I do not seem to have a `httpContext` in an added receiver.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using [System.Web.Caching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/8bx0tk8a) and Cache the entire object that is returned? You can also set absolute expiration for the cache so that it expires 24 hrs from thee current Date-Time.
The best practices you should follow for Object Caching are mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee558270%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Comment: Thx. But that is exactly the problem here. System.Web.Caching cannot be used directly. I need a HttpContext "somehwere" but there isn't any in this event receiver

Comment: I think this post can you help you achieve this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601352/how-to-obtain-the-httpcontext-in-event-handler